# I am having a little trouble in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a few hundred machines that are running different versions of MS Office. I need to find what machines are running what versions. I have a powershell script, I am able to obtain and export the names of the machines that have MS Office installed to a csv file, but I am having trouble getting the version of office installed on the machines to export to the csv as well. The code I am using is listed below:

```
$Computers = Get-Content "\\networkpath\ComputerList.txt"
$csvFilePath = "\\networkpath\SoftwareList.csv"

if (!(Test-Path -path $csvFilePath)) { ""|select name,version | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation}

$outputArray = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList


ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
        Get-WmiObject -computerName $computer -Class CIM_Product -Filter 'Name like "%Microsoft Office Professional Plus%"' | select name


$Version = select name
$row = ""|select name,version
$row.Name = $Computer.ToString()
$row.Version = $Version.ToString()
$outputArray.Add($row)
        }



$outputArray | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation #-Append
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not storing the version information for re-use in your Get-WmiObject... line.

A way to get the desired results would be to store the results from the get-wmiobject call to a variable, then use dot notation to get the specific properties you want.

```
$wmiObject = get-wmiobject win32_product ....
$wmiObject.Name
$wmiObject.Version
```

Typically, it's bad practice to format your objects using select, in-line, if you plan on re-using that object later on down the script.  As general guidance, I would store the raw object data in a variable, then format that variable later down the line.

```
# declare your array    
$outputarray = @()

# loop through your collection, build the custom psobject, and add it to your output array
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $wmiObject = get-wmiobject -computername $computer | where name -like 'Microsoft Office Proffesional Plus*'
    $obj = new-object -typename psobject
    $obj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name 'Name' -value $wmiObject.name
    $obj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name 'Version' -value $wmiObject.version
    $outputarray += $obj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like feral explain you, you dont store result of your wmi command.
I have simplified you code like this

```
$Computers = Get-Content "\\networkpath\ComputerList.txt"
$csvFilePath = "\\networkpath\SoftwareList.csv"

$Computers | 
    %{Get-WmiObject -computerName $_ -Class CIM_Product -Filter 'Name like "%Microsoft Office Professional Plus%"' | select PSComputerName, Name, Version} |
        Export-Csv $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information. I was just making it harder than what it needed to be and was ultimately able to get the data that I needed by changing the scripting taking out all of the cell information and exporting directly to a text file.

```
$$Computers = Get-Content "\\networkpath\ComputerList.csv"
$FilePath = "\\networkpath\SoftwareList.txt"

if (!(test-path $FilePath)){New-Item -Path $FilePath}
ForEach ($computer in $Computers)
{ 
$Result1 = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer  -Class CIM_Product -Filter 'Name like "%Microsoft Office Professional Plus%"' | select Name,Version 
$Result2 = Get-wmiobject Win32_computersystem -computer $computer | select name
$Result += $Result2, $Result1 |  Out-File -FilePath $Filepath -Append 
}
```